# Telegram bot on the python

Tags: sqlite

My telegram bot functions and buttons work first time but second time doesn't work. What should I do for my telegram bot work all time and when user enter random buttons, my bot continue working at the entered session. this my first bot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.